# How to achieve global fuzzy select in Gimp

Tags: gimp

How is it possible to fuzzy select overall in the image? By default Gimp only selects within the current region without going beyond boundaries. For instance I have a text for which to remove the background. For this is every O the background keeps unselected when not clicking within.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Select by color" tool [image] instead of the "fuzzy select".

You can also continue using the "Fuzzy select" and shift-click in the isolated areas to add them to the selection.